# Is there a way to make a pure vanila page of just HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: plugins

Bit of a odd question. I want to be able to host example simple websites on my Wordpress Site. These "simple" sites would just consist of client side code.

Is there a way to create a page which just uses these files, possible a plugin I am unaware of?

Thank you.

Comment: question is unclear. add more details. If you want to create stack html pages you can just put them on the wordpress directory and they will load when you visit them..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this in the past by using [custom page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).

Basically, there are two ways to create a custom page template.

1. You can create a file in your themes directory and name it `page-vanilla-html.php`.
2. You can create a file and name it whatever you want (for example `vanilla-html.php`). You just need to include a template description at the top of the file:

   ```
    <?php
    /*
     * Template Name: A Vanilla HTML/CSS/JS Custom Page Template
     * Description: This template is nothing but vanilla HTML/CSS/JS!
     */
    ?>
   ```

Once you've created the custom template, you simply create a new page within Wordpress. If the name of the page is "Vanilla HTML" it will search for a file named `page-vanilla-html.php` and load it automatically. If you used the second method, you can select the template from the drop down on the right side of the page creation screen.

Comment: Quick aside, while it will probably work to just put the <script> tags in the template, you're still better off using [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to add the js for these templates.  You can add conditional code within the callback function to only load the js when that template is loaded.

Comment: Ah execallent, I can then probably just create a few custom fields to auto load the data nicely into the file!

Comment: @AndrewBartel Enqueueing the script in this case is not a good idea. These are HTML/CSS/JS files - which implies PHP won't be used (except for the comment on top). This means no `wp_header()` or `wp_footer()`, and no enqueued scripts.

Comment: Ah, good point @RadGH.  And you're in Eugene too, that's cool!

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory named *(for example)* `example` in the root directory of your domain (where the WordPress `index.php` lives).

In that directory you can create your "simple" sites.
So if you create a HTML document named `mysite.htm` and visit `yourdomain.com/example/mysite.htm` the browser should display that page.

This is the default webserver behaviour - no need for a plugin.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that was what I was going to need to do, I was wondering if there was a way to do this within the control panel.

Comment: Yes, use [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) as mentioned in [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178454/17879) answer.